# Access Photo Library on iOS using Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, photo

I'm developing a simple application which displays an image from external storage and calculates the time in the disk access (I need to pass an URI from an specific image). 
I'm using Apache Cordova and Cordova-File-Plugin to access into sdcard. On Android, the app works fine, but I don't know how to access into the Photo Library on iOS...
I saw that some people use Cordova-Camera-Plugin for that and it works but it takes the image from "tmp" directory and it doesn't help me.

Anyone knows if it is posible?

Comment: See the documentation at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.htm. - is Library not what you want?

Comment: @ChrisN i cant access to that page, is the url correct?

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/ Try this? Works for me

Comment: @ChrisN Yes I tried with that plugin, works in Android but i can't access into Photo Library with iOS :/